# Change 404 status of default backend backend page

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a few application I want to host on a backend bucket. Some of these apps handle urls specifically.

So "example.com/shop", is handler by the app, and is not a file, which means the backend bucket returns 404 for that URL. So, I could configure the 404 page to be index.html, which works around this issue, however it returns a 404 status code.

The question is can I change the status code to 200?

Note that I can't use Firebase solutions due to other load balancing constraints. (I.e. /api/* needs to route directly to the api app)

Comment: Could you clarify what do you intend to do? what do you mean by "backend backend". Are you intending to serve an static webpage using Cloud Storage?

Comment: I meant backend bucket. Yes serve static webpage from cloud storage.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [Set a main page and/or error page for one or more buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/web).

> 3. There is just one 404.html page: For example, a GET request for http://www.example.com/photos/missing would retrieve http://www.example.com/404.html, not http://www.example.com/photos/404.html.

You achieve this by using `gsutil web set -e <404.html>` or you could use the [console](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#assign-pages) and insted of setting the `404` to an `404.html`, you just set it to the `index.html`.

Comment: Not just 404 page, but also 200 status!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that could be achieved using Cloud Storage only.